# How do I retrieve the value from table cell and send it to update page using jeditable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables, jeditable

I have mysql table-activity which has three columns, namely - id, clientname, status; and I am displaying only two columns, namely -,clientname and status using datatables.

Now I want to update my clientname value in database as well as displayed in my datatable dynamically on editing it. So for this, I used jeditable with datatable, but now I don't know how to retrieve the current cell's id and value and pass them through jeditable to my php page to edit them.Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.
Here is what i have tried so far-
  Html code-

```
<tbody  >
       <?php

            $sql= "SELECT * FROM `activity` ORDER BY clientname asc";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
          {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['clientname'];
            echo "<tr id=".$row['id']."class='edit_tr'>";
            echo $id;
              echo " <td class='edit'>".$row['clientname']."</td>
                   <td>".$row['status']."</td>
            </tr>";
          }

        ?>
    </tbody>
```

Jquery code-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
/* Init DataTables */
var oTable = $('#clientsheet').dataTable();

/* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
$('td', oTable.fnGetNodes()).editable( 'save.php', {
tooltip : 'Click cell to edit value...',
indicator : 'Saving...',
style : 'display:block;',
submit : 'OK',
cancel : 'Cancel',
data : " {'keyid':'id','keyname':'name'}",
type : 'select',
"Callback": function( sValue, x) {
var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]);

/* Redraw the table from the new data on the server */
oTable.fnClearTable( 0 );
oTable.fnDraw();
},
"submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
var aPos2 = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
var id2 = oTable.fnGetData( aPos2[0] ); 
return {
"row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
"id2": id2[0],
"column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[ 2 ] 
};
},
"height": "14px",
} );
} );
</script>
```

php code-

```
<?php
include('db.php');
 $sql = "UPDATE  `activity` SET clientname = '".$_POST['keyname']."' WHERE `id` = '".$_POST['id']."' ";
           if($nameresult = $conn->query($sql)){
          echo "successful";
          }
          else{
          echo "failed";
          }
          ?>
```

Please help me out..
Thanks in advance

Comment: just a note - you are going to have an orphaned text node in every row: `echo $id;`

Comment: @Pete..can you please help me out with making the changes in my code ..actually i am a newbie and quite fed up with this ....

Comment: unfortunately I don't know the plugin you are using so am unable to be any help

Comment: i am using jeditable plugin